# JavaFX Tableview make specific cells colored

Tags: css, javafx, tableview, css-specificity, tablecolumn

```
TableColumn tc = new TableColumn();

tc.getStyleClass.add(".style in css file")
```

i set up the tablecolumn with css file. and i want to make each cell has different backgrounds. is there any way to do it?

tableColumn row 1 bakcground color = green, row2 = red, row3 = blue....etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use setRowFactory for your TableView and change row style.
A little example there:

```
tableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Data_type>, TableRow<Data_type>>(){
            //There can define some colors.
            int color = 0;
            String colors[] = new String[]{"red","blue","green"};
            @Override
            public TableRow<Data_type> call(TableView<Data_type> param) {
                final TableRow<Data_type> row = new TableRow<Data_type>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Data_type item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        //there write your code to stylize row
                        if(getIndex() > -1){
                            String color = colors[getIndex() % 3];
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: "+ color + ";");

                        }
                    }
                };
                return row;
            }
        });
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Pro-tip: use `-fx-background` instead of `-fx-background-color`. This will preserve borders properly and also allow the text color to automatically adapt to the lightness/darkness of the background color.

Comment: when we scroll, the table view changes the colors