# TableView in JavaFX: how to change a single cell's background color if a TableCellTextField is being used?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am creating a TableCellTextField in all rows in the following column:

```
nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

My intention is to change the edited cell's background color depending on the user's input.

I have found several solutions for changing a single cell's background color which consist in overriding the updateItem() method inside the cell factory. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39782952/javafx-table-cell-back-ground-color) is an example.

However, I do not know how to combine that strategy with making the cell editable through a TextField.

Comment: There's an example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm (`EditingCell`). You just need to apply some customization on the `TextField`...

Comment: Subclassing `TextFieldTableCell` and overriding the `updateItem()` method should also work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically do the same thing with a `TextFieldTableCell` that you do with a regular `TableCell`. Note that, unlike a plain `TableCell`, a `TextFieldTableCell` already takes care of setting the text etc.

So you can do, e.g.:

```
PseudoClass specialClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("special");

nameColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> new TextFieldTableCell<MyType, String>(TextFormatter.IDENTITY_STRING_CONVERTER) {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        boolean condition = /* depends on item and empty.... */
        pseudoClassStateChanged(specialClass, condition);
    }
});
```

Then in your CSS file, just define the styles you need for the cell. E.g.

```css
.table-cell:special {
    -fx-background-color: yellow ;
}
```

Comment: That basically did it. Very simple solution, so much so that I almost feel embarrassed. Thanks!